# Do Ubuntu 20 LTS have 64bit image for i386 architecture

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

I was install by mistake 64bit AMD image on my Dell i386 do have 64bit image for it because I can`t find it.I don't want to be 32bit due lack of support for certain apps and programs.

Comment: `AMD64` is good for both AMD and Intel CPUs.

Comment: A computer with 32-bit architecture cannot use a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: What CPU is there in the computer (brand name and model)?

Comment: Yes is answer my question but the computer itself perform very slow with AMD version even its support 64bit.Its crash very often and is loading slow.This can be from the hardware itself is Dell Latitude e 6410.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 560  @ 2.67GHz

Comment: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/43560/intel-core-i7620m-processor-4m-cache-2-66-ghz.html  You have a 64-bit processor.  If it is crashing, you might want to get your hardware checked.  Also, the AMD64 would work fine for it.

Comment: OK thank you for the answer

Comment: Maybe your problem is that there is not enough RAM. How much RAM is there? If less than 3 GB, you had better use a light-weight community flavour of Ubuntu, for example Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Its have 4gb ram

Comment: Well, I understand that it is slow, but it should work reliably with Ubuntu, at least if you have a swap file or swap partition. Is your experience of running live from a USB drive or DVD disk, or from an installed system? Anyway, I have an old HP computer with similar specs (it was my daughter's computer until I 'inherited' it for testing **light-weight flavours of Ubuntu**).

Comment: You can check the RAM (with memtest) and the harddisk (S.M.A.R.T. data via Disks alias `gnome-disks`) and the file system (`sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn`) if installed.

Comment: I will test it latter thank you for that